# Adjective of or relating to "ember(s)"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I thought perhaps *embery* could be a word, but it isn't. Is there such a word?
Here's the sentence I intend to use it in: *He reached into the fire and grabbed an (embery) log.*

Comment: It doesn't really work. You would have to say _a log from among the embers_, or something like _a glowing log_.

Comment: @KateBunting Yeah, "glowing log" is what I currently have written down. "A log from among the embers" is pretty good though, could just add "glowing" in front of "log" in that sentence and it might be perfect.

Comment: @KateBunting has it exactly right. Given that an ember is "a small piece of burning or glowing coal or wood in a dying fire" (Lexico), one might even argue that an "embery log" is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 2):

I think ***[smoldering](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/smoldering)*** may suggest the idea you want to express:

> burning slowly without flame, usually emitting smoke.

*He reached into the fire and grabbed a smoldering log.*

(Collins)

From [Haunted America,](https://books.google.it/books?id=K-Z5yI9qlUUC&pg=PT88&dq=%22smoldering%20log%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-2Je2_OPpAhWDl4sKHf_UB_UQ6AEIWjAH#v=onepage&q=%22smoldering%20log%22&f=false)
By Michael Norman, Beth Scott

> Seated next to the faint glow of ***the fireplace's single smoldering log,*** Kim occasionally glanced through the mesh screen of the open fireplace into the lobby.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of smoldering, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that *embery* would be misunderstood, and it does follow the common method of turning some nouns into adjectives, but it might look strange.

It's something you could use in poetry, or enclose in quotation marks (to indicate it's been made up).

But you could also make use of [**-like**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like#h9):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **-like** *adjective combining form*
>   : resembling or characteristic of
>   // bell*-like*
>   // lady*like*

In the sentence in the question:

> He reached into the fire and grabbed an *ember-like* log.

Again, while probably not something to use in a formal context, it should be fine in most informal contexts.